# django production and development site on one server. experiences?

Tags: django, .htaccess

I am setting up a server to serve both the runtime and the development version.
Actually this would be only part of the game, let me explaining.

What I would like is:

```
www.mysite.com/site/: The site
www.mysite.com/site-dev-dhert45/: The dev site
```

They both run on the same DB but the 'dev' uses new eventual code or just
has debug=True or just has ADMIN activated.

And this is the question. how to?

To give more details here is the current situation.

On my server, at present, I have an .htaccess of this type:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ site_Random/django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^site-dev-dhert45/(.*)$ site_dev_Random/django.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I.e. I start two fully separated instance of fcgi.

By writing I realized that:

1. if I could have subdomains, it would be easy [I do not have subdomains]
2. The base domain is not served by django [which might made also something easier]

I would explore 2 approaches:

1. Trying to exploit the django.sites
2. Introduce a new settings.py variable 'URL_REWRITE_LOCATION' which will address the actual location

Any other suggestion?

While writing I realised that the subdomain solution solves actually my problem, but
before I owned the domain I had this problem. So I would leave the question for
my next case and as an exercise for myself ;)

And move to the next question, I will post here: how to properly address applications.

Comment: This might not be a good Idea for a couple reasonse.  There are tons of reasons not to do this 3 of which are:  1. developing with the dev server 2. sharing production data 3. exposing a url that has debug=True

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing the dev site at the subdomain level, something like 'dev.mysite.com' or following the "security through obscurity" method something random like 'hidden-dev-a0z9.mysite.com'. Then add authentication directly to that server/virtualhost using your http server (nginx/apache). That will really simplify the url naming process and make it very easy to develop, just a matter of changing your settings at the http server level.